# Errors importing module after using Pip to install with Python 3.9

Tags: python, numpy, pip

Apologies, but I'm a total python newbie and I'm really stuck with this.  I've got Python 3.9 on a PC, and am learning to code using PyCharm as my editor.  I've used Pip to import numpy but I'm getting an error when I add "import numpy" to my script:
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'numpy'

It looks like Pip downloaded it okay, and put it into the folder:
C:\Users\Alastair Heptonstall\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\Lib\site-packages\numpy

PyCharm appears to be using the correct version of python (it has Python 3.9 in the lower right corner of the screen).  And it looks like the version of Pip I used is the one that came with Python 3.9.

Is this error caused by a path not being set correctly?

Thanks for any help, very much appreciated!

Comment: PyCharm works with virtual environments. Did you install numpy through PyCharm or simply through the terminal and if its the latter, did you activate the correct environment beforehand?

Comment: Hi @pavel thanks for the response, I installed numpy through the terminal, not through PyCharm.  I don't think I know what activating the correct environment means.  I had already been using PyCharm and had it installed before I installed numpy from the terminal.  Thanks!

Comment: In PyCharm its better to install modules either through in-built Terminal (it should have the correct virtual environment activated) or through Settings-> Project Interpreter.

Comment: Thanks @pavel, that was the help I needed, I was able to use the "Python Packages" tool window to load it in PyCharm.  Problem solved!  Cheers!

Comment: Yes, as pavel said, Pycharm uses virtual environments so you may need to use pip install on that virtual environment or I suppose you could configure Pycharm to not use a virtual environment

Answer (score 1):

You can try this

**1.** Open **PyCharm**.

**2.** go to `File -> settings -> Project:untitled1 (untitled1 means your project name) -> select project interpretor -> click add button`

[image]

**3.** after clicking add button and **search** `<package name>` then **install** it.

finally, run the program.

---

**Newer versions of Pycharm have a "`+`" mark (add button) here.**

[image]